# How to know which knob to buy for my stove top?

Tags: stove

One of the knob of my stove top broke and I don't know which knob I need to buy. The knob that broke had a small thing inside to make it fit into the device to turn fire on/off, and that broke.

How do I know which knob I need to buy? I don't even know the brand/model of my stove top.

Here are the pictures of the knob that broke:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Somewhere on the unit there must be a tag that includes the make/model/serial number. If you can't find it, you probably just need to look harder. Open doors, pop off panels, it's there somewhere... (if not, look on google images until you find a picture that matches)

Comment: Try looking inside the oven door or its perimeter. You may be able to get a generic set of knobs at your local box store. I do not know if they sell them anymore.

Comment: push the knob onto the square post ... if it is loose, then fold a short, narrow strip of electrical tape across the end of the square post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can find on the Internet, you have an Ikea Range model ISE630WS00. I base this on the part number of the knob (W10159625), but it might simply be another model that is compatible with that knob.

I am having a hard time sourcing a replacement, but I would remove the plastic plug, put a little glue in there and put the plug back in. Would likely last quite a long time. Or search for a bit and try to find a replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you lost the spring clip. You could actually just glue it back on, if you're careful. I wouldn't imagine you actually need to take it off every other week.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my search, nobody makes that part anymore.

It used to be from Whirlpool OEM.

Take it to a shop and compare to others that might fit or try to glue it together.

**Or show your DIY skills** and rebuilding it.

Depending how it broke it might be fixable.

Starting with this part as firm base

[image: Amazon]

find the right size for you by measuring

[Shaft Collars Sets - Screw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000IL6AHS)